# Check if an array is sorted using Divide and Conquer

Tags: arrays, sorting, pseudocode, divide-and-conquer

As question says, I need to write an algorithm in C or Python which uses Divide-And-Conquer to check if an array is sorted or not. I have a basic idea, but I can't seem to reach a definitive answer.
This is what I got so far, using pseudocode:

```
isSorted(array, start, end):
    if (len(array)) <= 1: return true
    if (end - start) == 1: return array[end] > array[start]
    middle = (end + start) // 2
    return isSorted(array, start, middle) && isSorted(array, middle, end)
```

Would that do the trick? Or am I missing some border cases in which this algorithm wouldn't work?

Comment: That will cause a stack overflow exception.  You don't handle the case where start == end.  You might think you do with the len(array), but that is the full array, not a partial array passed into the current scope.

Comment: So the first mistake can be corrected by adding another condition if start == end return true. And my second mistake, I can use end - start instead of using len.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my own question, I was quite there but there were some problems that I was marked in the comments. One of them was that I didn't handle when there were duplicates in the array, and len(array) wouldn't work properly, since I never changed the array.

```
def isSorted(array, start, end):
    if start == end: return True
    if (end - start) == 1: return array[end] >= array[start]
    middle = (end + start) // 2
    return isSorted(array, start, middle) and isSorted(array, middle, end)
```

That's programmed in Python, very close to the pseudocode above, and it works for the cases I made.